# Assert the two ArrayList<ClassA> with the ArrayList<ClassB> using Steam API

Tags: java

have two json list one json list has 2 json object and class type is classA and 2nd json list has 4 json objects and class type is classB so want to assert 1st json object of list one with all 4 objects 2nd json list and retrun true if one is match with at least one json objects of 2nd list

Sample of class A:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

public class classA {

    private String fromPartyId;

    private PartyType fromType;
}
```

And Sample of Class B:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder

public class classB {

    private String fromPartyId;

    private PartyType fromType;
}
```

Json Data for the Class A:

```
[
    {
        "fromPartyId": 1265389,
        "fromType": "T168716355035036378"
    },
    {
    "fromPartyId": 1265389,
    "fromType": "T168716355035036379"
    }

]
```

Sample data for class B:

```
    [
    {
      "fromPartyId": "13916fb0-fa83-40aa-a452-37de08e392ba",
      "fromType": "MERCHANT"
    },
    {
      "fromPartyId": "ce2593b1-2cc4-46c7-b1fe-9a57990f593c",
      "fromType": "INTERCHANGE"
    },
    {
      "fromPartyId": "ce2593b1-2cc4-46c7-b1fe-9a57990f593c",
      "fromType": "INTERCHANGE"
    },
    {
      "fromPartyId": "ce2593b1-2cc4-46c7-b1fe-9a57990f593c",
      "fromType": "INTERCHANGE"
    }
  ]
```

NOTE: `PartyType` is enum.

able to assert a one key and value but want assert all the keys and values at once.

```
boolean anyMatch = classB.stream().anyMatch(element -> element.getPartyId().contains(classA.getPartyId()));
```

Want to match the keys and value of class A with class B with help of java steam.

Comment: What exactly is "assert first hashmap with second, if any data set doesn't match then need to check for the next data set." supposed to mean?

Comment: second json array has two objects and first json array has 4 index, so basically want to compare 1st index of second json object with all the objects first json if any match then will return true and same want to do with second index also. @user207421

Comment: @user207421 have updated the question, can you please check.

Comment: And what would the result be? What does "match A with B" mean exactly? Do you want to merge the two lists? Do you want to update list A with values from list B? Do you want to create a new list C with A and B tied together?

Comment: Match in what way? The data in the two JSONs don't look similar. Why use streams? Also your choice of classes is strange. On the one hand the class structures are the same, so way are these two different classes? On the other hand, the one JSON is using numbers instead of strings for `fromPartyId`, so why isn't that represented in the class?

Comment: @knittl want to assert the keys and value with class A and class B, expectation is, if all values and matched then return true else return false.

Comment: How do you want to match? On id? On id+type? Something else? How should duplicates be handled? In your given example, no two objects are equal

Comment: Want to match based on json objects like LedgerEntryResponseActual.fromPartyId == LedgerResponseExpected.fromPartyId.

yeah, On id+type. @knittl

Comment: Can you implement equals/hashCode in one of your classes? (But why is it not a single class since both properties are the same?)

Answer (score 0):

Wrong understanding of concepts. You should only have one class `LedgerResponse` and have 2 instances of list and than just compare 2 lists

Comment: LedgerResponseExpected is my expected which I'm deserialising from expected json and LedgerEntryResponseActual to use in deserialisation of response which i'm getting from api, and then i need to validate the value and keys from LedgerResponseExpected to LedgerEntryResponseActual. @Michael Gantman

Comment: They are not different classes they should be 2 different instances of the same class

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at AssertJ which is fantastic for all types of assertions, including collections. AssertJ has far better failure messages than the usual "expected true, found false"

https://assertj.github.io/doc/

Eg

```java
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors.*

List<ClassA> listA = parseJson("a.json", ClassA.class);
List<ClassB> listB = parseJson("b.json", ClassB.class);

Set<String> stringsA = listA.stream(0)
   .map(a -> String.format("%s:%s", a.fromPartyId, a.fromType)
   .collect(toSet());

assertThat(listB)
   .extracting(b -> String.format("%s:%s", b.fromPartyId, b.fromType)
   .containsAnyElementsOf(stringsA);
```